# why main P2((ac, av), int ac, char ** av) ？

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system

Recently, I am reading the source code of GSM audio coding. These codes are written in 1992 or later.

There are some strange codes like:

```
main P2((ac, av), int ac, char ** av)

void Gsm_Coder P8((S,s,LARc,Nc,bc,Mc,xmaxc,xMc)
```

Are those codes used the old method? What's the use of P2 or P8?

Comment: I imagine `P2` and `P8` are macros.  Track down the macro definitions to find out what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

These are macros that make the code compatible with old-style compilers that listed the types after the parentheses.  E.g., `P2` could expand to

```
main(int ac, char **av)
```

or

```
main(ac,av)
int ac;
char **av;
```

Run `gcc -E` to see the preprocessed output.

The `2` and `8` are because preprocessor macros in older compilers can't have a variable number of parameters, so you need a separate macro for each parameter count.